# Bluetooth issue after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, updates

I just upgraded my computer form Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 using the terminal. Everything went fine (except for some issues with the video card embedded in the motherboard but I was expecting this and I should have fixed it) but now I cannot turn on the bluetooth switch. I have a bluetooth dongle (Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3011 Bluetooth, according to lsusb) but I did not menage to turn it on. If I run `sudo modprobe btusb` I get an erro message saying:

`modprobe: FATAL: Module btusb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1053-gke`

I have upgraded (both with `update` and `dist-update`) but all package are up to date.

The output of `service bluetooth status` is:

```
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

The output of `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:5d17 HP, Inc HP LaserJet P2035
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3000 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3011 Bluetooth (no firmware)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Hey!
Did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: I changed the kernel to the generic version using uktools (https://github.com/usbkey9/uktools) and then it worked again!